# GCP AI Platform Vertex endpoint model undeploy : 404 The DeployedModel with ID `2367889687867` is missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to un-deploy model from an endpoint following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.Endpoint#google_cloud_aiplatform_Endpoint_undeploy).

```
Endpoint.undeploy(deployed_model_id=model_id)
```

I even tried [google api](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.endpoints/undeployModel). Same Issue with this as well.

Getting 404 error

> The Deployed Model with ID `2367889687867` is missing.

**INFO:**

1. Both model and Endpoint are in same region.
2. There is a single model deployed in the endpoint with `traffic_percentage=100`.

Comment: Does [`list_models`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.Endpoint#google_cloud_aiplatform_Endpoint_list_models) include it?

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes It does. While doing so I found the DeployedModel ID is different from model ID. I looked everywhere in GCP console couldn't find it . But I see the ID in list_models, and with this ID I am able to undeploy works.

Comment: Is there a way to get Deployed Model ID from deployed_model_display_name under a particular endpoint? or using list_models and then dissecting is the only way?

Comment: If the answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deployed_model_id` is different from the `model_id`.That’s why you are getting the Error 404, it is searching for something that is not the same.

You can get the `deployed_model_id` by:

- list_models()
- list()

Using `list_models()` brings you a list of all the deployed models ids, while using `list()` only brings one, you can add filters such as `display_name`, `model_id`, `region`, etc.

```
list(
    filter= ‘display_name= “display_name”’,
)
```

You also can get the `deployed_model_id` using the Cloud SDK.

```
gcloud ai models list --region=$REGION --filter="DISPLAY_NAME: $NAME" | grep "MODEL_ID" | cut -f2 -d: | sed 's/\s//'
```

Additionally, you can specify the `deployed_model_id` when you are deploying your model using Cloud SDK the command should look like:

```
gcloud ai endpoints deploy-model $endpoint --project=$project --region=$region --model=$model_id --display-name=$model_name --deployed-model-id=$deployed_model_id
```

There are some flags that are required when you deploy a model such as endpoint, project, region, model and display name. And there are others that are [optional flags](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/endpoints/deploy-model#:%7E:text=the%20uploaded%20model.-,OPTIONAL%20FLAGS,-%2D%2Daccelerator%3D%5Bcount) that you can use deployed_model_id is one of them.(I don’t know if this is possible but you could set the deployed_model_id as the same as the model_id).